# AWS SDK for Ruby でamiのidを取得する方法

Tags: ruby, aws

## 前提・実現したいこと前提

AWS SDK for Ruby でamiのidを取得したい

## 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

[AWS SDK for Ruby V2](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Image.html)
こちらを参考にさせていただいて

```rb
   require 'aws-sdk'
   ec2 = Aws::EC2::Resource.new(region: 'ap-northeast-1')

  ec2.images.each do |i|
    puts "ID:    #{i.image}"
  end
```

というプログラムを組んでみたのですが、実行すると何も表示されず困っています。
どうかお力添えいただけますと幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

## 補足情報

amiは作成済みです。
SDKは動作します。

ruby 2.3.3
AWS SDK for Ruby V2
ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 0):

ドキュメントには`image`ではなく[`image_id`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/EC2/Image.html#image_id-instance_method)とありますが？

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
imageをimage_idと変えてみて実行してみたところ
id.rb:4:in `<main>': undefined method `image_id' for #<Aws::EC2::Resource:0x005593250269b8> (NoMethodError)
Did you mean?  image
このようなエラーになってしまいます。

Answer (score 0):

まずは`i`の中身を確認してみるのはどうでしょうか？

```
ec2.images.each do |i|
  p i
end
```

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。中身を確認するためにおしゃっていた通りにプログラムを変更してみたのですが、iの中身も帰ってこないです。

Comment: 中身が返ってこないというのは不思議ですね。
元のコードで`Aws::EC2::Resource` がNoMethodErrorを返しているので何かしら表示されそうなものですが・・・

Answer (score 0):

その対象の image は、確かに東京リージョンに作成されていますか？別リージョンになっていたりしませんか？